# Take non-null value from one of several columns in polars

Tags: python, python-polars

Having dataframe

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
{
    "a": [1, None, None],
    "b": [None, 2, None],
    "c": [None, None, 3],
    "non_relevant": [1, 2, 3],
})
```

I wish to produce result

```py
result = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1, 2, 3],
        "non_relevant": [1, 2, 3],
    }
)
```

With knowledge of

```py
remapping = {"a": ("a", "b", "c"), "other_key": ("aN", "bN", "cN")}
```

I would like this function to throw if combination ever results in multiple non-null combinations. In my use case, there are a lot of columns to be combined this way.

Comment: why does `non-relevant` go from 0,1,2 to 1,2,3 and what is `other_key` supposed to do?

Comment: I had an error in the question regarding the `non_relevant`  which is now corrected. Other key is supposed to represent the other remaps that I have to do. I have `N` similar mappings in that dictionary.

Comment: Maybe start with [`pl.coalesce`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.coalesce.html#polars-coalesce)?

Comment: `pl.coalesce` seems to do the case if single value is known to exist. This will suffice with more confirmation code before combination. @Wayoshi Thank you.